# PHP: functions that return arrays: how to get a exact copy of returned array

Tags: php, arrays, deep-copy

When a function in php returns an array and I assign it to a varialble such a 'user' bellow. It copies the array and put it space [0]

```
$user = query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);



Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cash] => 127046553.2710
            [id] => 8
            [username] => test
            [hash] => $1$w40Hc/vl$45jJlZ/1x1rqQlEEQP7hE1
        )

)
```

So then I have to do this:

```
if ($user[0]["cash"])
```

But it would be better do just ask the array for "cash". What is the standard way of doing this in php?

```
if ($user["cash"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the function 'query' you use.

The function does return (I would guess) an array of all returned rows. So if there would be more users you would get `0=>user1, 1=>user2`, etcetera.

If you're sure that you will only get one user you can do the following:

```
$user = query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);
$user = $user[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace/overwrite the array.

```
$user = $user[0];
```

Comment: Is that really the way of doing it in php? it would ad redudant code it seems to me.

Comment: With the code you've provided, it's the best we can do. Redundant code would mean code that's not being used. This code is being used to accomplish your desired result, thus, not redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Simply re-assign it beforehand...

```
  $user = $user[0] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.4+ you can do the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ?";
$user  = query($query, $_SESSION["id"])[0];
```

Notice the `[0]` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Re-assignment works, however this is '[code-smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)' which is telling you something might need to be further [abstracted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16070/what-is-abstraction) or [refactored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring?sort=votes&pageSize=15).

Your query function is returning the complete set of rows which match the query, which is what it should be doing. You might wish to add another function, possibly `query_firstResult()`, to return just the [0] element. Or you might add a parameter to query() like `$all = true` or `$singleResult = false`.

A good rule of thumb is: "if I have to do a work-around once, or even twice, it's okay, but if I have to do it a third time it's time to fix it."

Answer (score -1):

just use this, hope can help,

```
$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"])) or die(mysql_error());
```

using some error handling will be more help than nothing at all, use `mysql_fetch_array()` for singel row, then access your data using `$user['cash']`

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated and not favoured for future (and current) developments. It also doesn't support prepared statements.

Comment: yes, i know that, but for some purpose some of us still using it, and i though is good for some example cause we more familiar with that one